# Font file from assets folder ,set to textview of custom layout is not visible android

Tags: android

I tried to change the typeFace of textview located in custom layout . When is set font to the textview , the textview become invisible ,but in the raw layout file I can see the typeFace changed but not reflecting programatically .... please help me to solve this

list_row.xml   // custom layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#F0F0F0"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dip">

    <!-- ListRow Left sied Thumbnail image -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/list_row"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:background="@drawable/image_bg"
        android:padding="3dip" >

        <!-- THUMBAIL IMAGE -->

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/list_image"
            android:layout_width="85dip"
            android:layout_height="80dip"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:shadowColor="#585858"
            android:shadowDx="0.0"
            android:shadowDy="0.0"
            android:shadowRadius="20"
            android:src="@drawable/karthik" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sub_title_category"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="Facebook Friend"
        android:textColor="#10bcc9"
        android:textSize="12dip"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
    <!-- ARROW IMAGE -->


    <!-- NAME -->
    <!-- CONTACT NUMBER -->


    <!-- BIRTHDATE -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/list_row"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/list_row"
        android:text="KARTHIK.KOLANJI"
        android:textColor="#181818"
        android:textSize="16dip"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="sans" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtview_type_of_reminder"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/list_row"
        android:layout_below="@+id/list_row"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dip"
        android:text="(Anniversary)"
        android:textColor="#181818"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="normal" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtview_zodiac"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/TextView02"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/TextView02"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/TextView02"
        android:text="Sagittarius"
        android:textColor="#181818"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="normal" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView01"
        android:layout_width="20dip"
        android:layout_height="20dip"
        android:layout_above="@+id/txtview_type_of_reminder"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txtview_zodiac"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:shadowColor="#8B4513"
        android:shadowDx="0.0"
        android:shadowDy="0.0"
        android:shadowRadius="20"

        android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
        android:contentDescription="Zodiac icon"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtview_turns"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/list_image_arrow"
        android:layout_below="@+id/list_image_arrow"
        android:text="24"
        android:textColor="#181818"
        android:textSize="20sp"
         />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/txtview_type_of_reminder"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txtview_type_of_reminder"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/TextView02"
        android:text="Next birthday on : "
        android:textColor="#181818"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="normal" 
        android:layout_marginTop="3dip"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtview_next_bd"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/TextView01"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/TextView01"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/TextView01"
        android:text="Wednesday"
        android:textColor="#181818"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="normal" 
        android:layout_marginTop="2dip"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sub_title_contact_number"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/title_name"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/list_row"
        android:text="9594080469"
        android:textColor="#181818"
        android:textSize="15dip" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sub_title_birthdate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/sub_title_contact_number"
        android:layout_below="@+id/sub_title_contact_number"
        android:text="7th, April 1990"
        android:textColor="#181818"
        android:textSize="15dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dip" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView02"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ImageView01"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/list_row"
        android:text="Zodiac :  "
        android:textColor="#181818"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="normal" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_image_arrow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/sub_title_birthdate"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/sub_title_category"
        android:text="t u r n s"
        android:textColor="#181818"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textStyle="normal" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView04"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ImageView01"
        android:text=" days left"
        android:textColor="#181818"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textStyle="normal" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtview_days_left"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/txtview_next_bd"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txtview_next_bd"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txtview_turns"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="365"
        android:textColor="#181818"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

SearchListActivity.java    // refering custom layout file

```
public class SearchListActivity extends ListActivity {

    String from[];
    int to[];
    CustomCursorAdapter adapter;

    TextView emptyView;

    @SuppressLint("NewApi") @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.search_list_activity);
        Cursor cursor;
        adapter=new CustomCursorAdapter(this, cursor);
        cursor=cursorLoader.loadInBackground();
        from=new String[]{BirthdayProvider.NAME,BirthdayProvider.NUMBER,BirthdayProvider.CATEGORY,BirthdayProvider.EVENT_TYPE,BirthdayProvider.EVENT_DAY,BirthdayProvider.TURNS_AGE,BirthdayProvider.EVENT_WEEK,BirthdayProvider.WESTERN_ZODIAC,BirthdayProvider.DAYS_REMAINING};
        to=new int[]{R.id.title_name,R.id.sub_title_contact_number,R.id.sub_title_category,R.id.txtview_type_of_reminder,R.id.sub_title_birthdate,R.id.txtview_turns,R.id.txtview_next_bd,R.id.txtview_zodiac,R.id.txtview_days_left};
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {

            adapter=new CustomSimpleCursor(this, R.layout.list_row, cursor, from, to);
            getListView().setAdapter(adapter);
        }
        else
        {
            emptyView=(TextView)getListView().findViewById(android.R.id.empty);
        }

        setFont();
    }

    public void setFont(){
        LayoutInflater inflater=LayoutInflater.from(this);
        View view =inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

        Typeface font;
        TextView txtDaysRemainig=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtview_days_left);
        font=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "CROCHET PATTERN.ttf");
        txtDaysRemainig.setTypeface(font);
    }
}
```

CustomCursorAdapter .java

```
public class CustomCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter{

    Typeface font;
    TextView txtDaysRemainig,txtTurnsAge;

    public CustomCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
        super(context, c);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View arg0, Context arg1, Cursor cursor) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String year=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(BirthdayProvider.EVENT_YEAR));
        String month=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(BirthdayProvider.EVENT_MONTH));
        String date=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(BirthdayProvider.EVENT_DATE));
        String remainingDays=BirthdayCalculation.getDaysRemainingForNextBirthDay(year, month, date);
        txtDaysRemainig.setText(remainingDays);
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor arg1, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater mInflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, parent, false);

        txtDaysRemainig = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtview_days_left);
        font=Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "CrochetPattern.ttf");
        txtDaysRemainig.setTypeface(font);
        // edit: no need to call bindView here. That's done automatically
        return view;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that your `ttf` file is located in your `assets` directory.

Then I suggest that you rename the ttf "CROCHET PATTERN.ttf" into "CrochetPattern.ttf", maybe the "space" is a trouble here.

**EDIT :**
I didn't realize that you were in a `ListView`.
You need to set the `TypeFace` in the `newView` method of your adapter. So here you'll need to override from `CursorAdapter`. Like in this code :

```
public class CustomCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
    private Context context;
    LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public AreaCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
        // that constructor should be used with loaders.
        super(context, c, 0);
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }


    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        // put the data on your views           

    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, parent, false);
        Typeface font;
        TextView txtDaysRemainig = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtview_days_left);
        font=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "CrochetPattern.ttf");
        txtDaysRemainig.setTypeface(font);
        // edit: no need to call bindView here. That's done automatically
        return v;
    }

}
```

Because before you were modifying a `TextView` from a layout who wasn't attached anywhere.

And replace :

```
adapter=new CustomSimpleCursor(this, R.layout.list_row, cursor, from, to);
```

by

```
adapter = new CustomCursorAdapter(this, cursor);
```

Comment: there is not problem with the font name....after changing to "CrochetPattern.ttf" , the result is same

Comment: Can you describe the path of your ttf in your project ?

Comment: it is directly placed into assets folder like "assets/CROCHET PATTERN.ttf"

Comment: there is only problem with the custom layout list_row.xml...If I use these font with MainActivity.java of main_activity.xml ,it works

Comment: I am trying to use your code in CustomSimpleCursor .java. This also makes my textview invisible

Comment: There was an error in my answer, I replaced : android.R.layout.list_row by R.layout.list_row don't know if it helps. Otherwise if your TextView is invisible I think it's a bug in your layout ...

Comment: pls have a look at my new CustomCursorAdapter .java

Comment: if I omit this line "txtDaysRemainig.setTypeface(font);". The textview is visible

Comment: sorry to say still same result ......if I omit this line "txtDaysRemainig.setTypeface(font);". The textview is visible

Comment: So it's a problem with your ttf ... did your rename it "CrochetPattern.ttf" ?

Comment: I tried with other tectview of the list_row.xml ,it works .what is the problem with "txtDaysRemainig" ????

Answer (score 0):

try setting text like `txtDatsRemaining.setText("365");`  manually after setting typeface

Comment: txtDatsRemaining.setText("365"),after using this I able to see the textview ,but with default font and not the custom font that I set